# Intercepting Android Notifications based on associated audio file?

Tags: android, audio, notifications

Basically what the title is saying. I'm trying to make a small app that can determine what audio file was just played for a notification, and react based on that. Is there a way to monitor all incoming notifications on android to get this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the "Accessibility Service" as a way to read all incoming system notifications, and then handled them appropriately depending on what type of even was happening. I discovered that this is also how applications like Tasker handle similar functionality.

More information is available here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Comment: Does this allow you to find media played from any app or just the native media player?  What about if you are listening to streaming audio?

Comment: I gotta give you massive props on this one because your suggestion helped me find a possible solution for a lot of things I am trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

No, the stream of notifications is not available to applications. (It would be a security hole, allowing any installed app to read your email, for example.)

Comment: So how does this work for applications similar to "tasker" that do not require root access?